MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 TorchSharp.ModuleExtensionMethods.to(!!0, Device)' after upgrade
I upgraded nuget packages from:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML" Version="3.0.0-preview.23266.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics" Version="3.0.0-preview.23266.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.TorchSharp" Version="0.21.0-preview.23266.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.Vision" Version="3.0.0-preview.23266.6" />
<PackageReference Include="TorchSharp-cuda-windows" Version="0.99.5" />

to:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.TorchSharp" Version="0.21.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.Vision" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="TorchSharp-cuda-windows" Version="0.102.5" />

And now when try load torch model
MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();
//this place    
ITransformer mlModel = mlContext.Model.Load(MLNetModelPath, out var _);

I catch exception:
MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 TorchSharp.ModuleExtensionMethods.to(!!0, Device)'.
at Microsoft.ML.TorchSharp.AutoFormerV2.ObjectDetectionTransformer.Create(Microsoft.ML.Runtime.IHostEnvironment, Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext)

There were no problems with previous versions of these packages.
Why did this problem appear now and how to fix it?
I try find any information on mslearn and github, expecting to find an answer or examples there

Package Microsoft.ML.TorchSharp (0.21.1) requires TorchSharp (>= 0.101.5) and respectively TorchSharp-cuda-windows (>= 0.101.5)
screenshot
But latest version TorchSharp (0.102.5) suddenly has no method overloading '!!0 TorchSharp.ModuleExtensionMethods.to(!!0, Device)'
To solve this problem: downgrade version TorchSharp-cuda-windows to (0.101.5),
If TorchSharp places in Transitive packages it will downgraded automatically to (0.101.5)
This solution will also work for TorchSharp-cpu and TorchSharp-cuda-linux
