Unable to load DLL 'LibTorchSharp' or one of its dependencies: The specified procedure could not be found
I'm attempting to use ML.NET to build a model for a simple text classification, but using the CPU rather than GPU due to lacking one with CUDA. However, trying to execute my current code results in the following error message, and I can not for the life of me figure out how to fix it:

System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'LibTorchSharp' or one of its dependencies: The specified procedure could not be found. (0x8007007F)'

I have references to the following packages in the project, so it should be present:
    <PackageReference Include="libtorch-cpu-win-x64" Version="2.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.TorchSharp" Version="0.21.1" />

I've tried importing the more-general packages of TorchSharp or TorchSharp-cpu as well, but that results in different exceptions stemming from it trying to access the CUDA packages, so I'm assuming that's not the solution. I've also tried reducing the versions of these packages, but with no success there either.
I was able to recreate the issue in a minimal console application that just calls the following class:
using Microsoft.ML;
using Microsoft.ML.TorchSharp;

namespace MLTest;
class TestClass
{
  public void MakeMLModel()
  {
    MLContext mlContext = new()
    {
      FallbackToCpu = true,
      GpuDeviceId = null
    };
    var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(GetData());
    var pipeline =
      mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label", "Category")
        .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.TextClassification(sentence1ColumnName: "Text"))
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));
    var model = pipeline.Fit(data);
  }

  private class DataObject
  {
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
  }

  private IEnumerable<DataObject> GetData()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
      DataObject x = new() { Category = (i % 4).ToString(), Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[i%26].ToString() };
      yield return x;
    }
  }
}

The data here is just garbage standing in for my actual project's data, of course, but it still fails on the .Fit call with the same exception. What exactly am I doing wrong? I am able to add a model through the ML.NET model builder, so it doesn't seem like the problem should be something about the lack of CUDA at least, but I can't find any information on the error message regarding a missing procedure anywhere.

This trainer requires a GPU with CUDA support, even if you've specified FallbackToCpu = true.
To solve this problem, you need to use an alternative text classification method that does not require a GPU.
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey("Label", "Category")
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Features", "Text"))
    .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaMaximumEntropy("Label", "Features"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

Or others

After messing with it for a while I did actually end up getting it to work. It does require using the TorchSharp-cpu package instead of the Windows-specific TorchSharp-cpu-win-x64 one. It gives a strange error message if you try to use the current version of the package, but that can be fixed by downgrading to version 0.101.5 as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78630239/missingmethodexception-method-not-found-0-torchsharp-moduleextensionmethods
